# SLComposeViewController - SLServiceTypeTwitter, addImage issue

Tags: twitter, ios7, social-networking, attachment

Here is what I am facing using SLComposeViewController to generate a tweet in an iOS app.

First of all this is my code:

```
- (IBAction)twitButtonHandler:(id)sender
{
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        tweetController.completionHandler=nil;

        [tweetController setInitialText:@"Hello this is a tweet."];

        if (![tweetController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyNicePicture.png"]]) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to add the image!");
        } else NSLog(@"Add the image OK!");

        [self presentViewController:tweetController animated:YES completion:Nil];

    } else {
        // The device cannot send tweets.
        NSLog(@"No Tweet possible!");
        return;
    }
}
```

The above code works fine except for the fact that I never see the image in the actual tweet though it always displays the message "Add the image OK!" in the debugger. Can anyone see something wrong in the code? Or tell me where could be a potential problem?

Comment: The code you're showing simply presents the SLComposeViewController view. Do you *see* your image file attached or somehow indicated in the view before you hit the "post" button?

Comment: No, this is precisely the problem: the view is not attached. But, if instead of tweeting I mail, then I can see the image is there.

Comment: I bet it's because you can tweet JPG or GIF files but ***not*** png files.

Answer (score 0):

Digging more into the issue on my own made me discover that :

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyNicePicture.png"]
```

was returning nil.

From that point everything is explained and the problem has to do with the way I get the UIImage object, not with SLComposeViewController and SLServiceTypeTwitter as I first thought.